# Need to retain values in text fields after calling the function more than once

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a button, I have a table called [input norm] and two fields ITEM AND MFG and i have written the code inside like this, When i click on button it should retain the value of msgstr and when it is calling function for the second time the old Text32.Value also should be retained.
For example, In my case when i call the function `CheckColumnType_TEXT("INPUT NORM", "ITEM")` it will display 'ITEM is not TEXT type'-it is correct in this scenario, but when it calls  `Call CheckColumnType_TEXT("INPUT NORM", "MFG")`it will display 'MFG is not TEXT type' which is correct as well, But the problem is, Text32.Value stores the latest value i.e MFG is not TEXT type, But I want both **ITEM is not TEXT type** and **MFG is not TEXT type** to be retained in my Text32.Value field. Any help would be greatly appreciated
[image]

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim str As String
    Call CheckColumnType_TEXT("INPUT NORM", "ITEM")
    Call CheckColumnType_TEXT("INPUT NORM", "MFG")
    End Sub

Function CheckColumnType_TEXT(TblName As String, ColName As String)
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim tbl_nks As DAO.TableDef
Set tbl_nks = db.TableDefs("[INPUT NORM]")
If ifFieldExists(ColName, "[INPUT NORM]") Then
If (tbl_nks.Fields(ColName).Type = dbText) = False Then
Dim msgstr As String
msgstr = msgstr & ColName & " is not TEXT Type" + vbCrLf
'Return msgstr
Text32.Value = msgstr
Text32.ForeColor = vbBlue
'status.Value = ""
'Exit Function
Else
End If
Else
MsgBox ColName & " field is not available", vbCritical
'status.Value = ""
End If
End Function

    Public Function ifFieldExists(FLDNAME As String, TableName As String) As Boolean
Dim rs As Recordset, db As DAO.Database 'Sub DAO Vars
On Error GoTo fs
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select " & FLDNAME & " from " & TableName & ";")
ifFieldExists = True
rs.Close
db.Close
Exit Function
fs:
Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
ifFieldExists = False
Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise the TextBox at the start of your processing:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim str As String
    Text32.Value = ""
    Call CheckColumnType_TEXT("INPUT NORM", "ITEM")
    Call CheckColumnType_TEXT("INPUT NORM", "MFG")
End Sub
```

and then update it each time you check a column:

```
Function CheckColumnType_TEXT(TblName As String, ColName As String)
    '...
    '...
    'Dim msgstr As String
    If Text32.Value <> "" Then
        Text32.Value = Text32.Value & vbCrLf
    End If
    Text32.Value = Text32.Value & ColName & " is not TEXT Type"
    '...
```